# Which is this curve?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

What curve is given from $$\gamma (\theta)=\left (\sin (\theta +c)\cos \theta , \sin (\theta +c)\sin \theta \right ), \text{ where } c \text{ is a constant } $$ ? How can we find it?

Comment: Have you tried squaring and adding? You can eliminate $\theta$ in a few steps and get a cartesian equation of a circle

Comment: Do you mean $$(\sin (\theta +c)\cos \theta)^2+(\sin (\theta +c)\sin \theta)^2=\sin^2(\theta +c)\cos^2 \theta+\sin^2 (\theta +c)\sin^2 \theta \\ =\sin^2 (\theta +c)=(\sin(\theta+c))^2=(\sin \theta \cos c+\cos \theta \sin c)^2 \\ =\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 c+\cos^2 \theta \sin^2 c+2\sin \theta \cos \theta \sin c\cos c $$ ? How could we continue? @DavidQuinn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT....You have $$x^2+y^2=\sin^2(\theta+c)$$
So $$\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sin\theta\cos c+\cos\theta\sin c$$
Furthermore, $$\tan\theta=\frac yx$$
Can you finish this?

Comment: How can we use $\tan \theta=\frac{y}{x}$ ? I got stuck right now...

Comment: You can get $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ in terms of $x$ and $y$

Comment: How? Do we write $\tan \theta=\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$ ?

Comment: Draw a right angled triangle with opposite side $y$ and adjacent side $x$....

Comment: Then we have $\sin \theta =\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\cos \theta =\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, right?

Comment: And the hypotenuse is....?

Comment: I edited my comment... it is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, right?

Comment: Then we have $$\pm (x^2+y^2)=y \cos c+x \sin c$$ right?